# PostgreSQL running more than one statement at a time

Tags: postgresql

I am running some cleanup scripts on my data, and I can't figure out how to execute more than one statement at a time.

Ex:

```
select count(*) from table where column1 = 'new'

select * from table where column1 <> 'new'
```

If I highlight both lines a try to execute them (like in MS management Studio), I get

> "ERROR: syntax error at or near "select" SQL state: 42601 Character:
>   59"

Is it possible? It is very annoying to run each separately since I need to see both results.

Comment: try adding a semicolon after each query.

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: pgAdmin lll ver 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Just add ; on end of the statement.

```
select count(*) from table where column1 = 'new';
select * from table where column1 <> 'new';
```

Comment: then only the first statement runs

Comment: there is no effect to run more then one select query because you get result from only one. But if you have update/delete statement this should work. At last in ems posgresql manager.

Comment: So is there no way to run more than one select statement at a time?

Comment: I far as I know you can run multiple query, but will show result from only one.

Comment: That's a shame, oh well.  Thanks anyway